# Adding arrows to rising edges of pulse plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, graphics, plot, matplotlib

Need help in matplotlib to figure out the answers for,

1. How do you make an arrow pointing up and an arrow pointing down along a curve/line on the plot?
2. How do you adjust the range/limits of the plot so that the edges of it are visible clearly on the graph?

I wanted to add arrows on the rising edge of a pulsing wave, (a down arrow on the falling edges of the pulse would be a bonus) and could not figure out an easy way to do it (the examples on the annotation page serve a different purpose altogether).

Since a picture makes things clearer, my code is:

```
from pylab import *

# How do I have arrows pointing up for every even value and pointing down for every odd value along Y axis for the highest freq.

baseFreqTimePeriod = 100
samplingFreqTimePeriod = 0.001

numberOfPulses = 10

def baseFreq(inputTime, timePeriod):

    sampleWindow = timePeriod

    return [ (1.0/(timePeriod/baseFreqTimePeriod)) if((i % sampleWindow) <= (sampleWindow / 2)) else 0.0 for i in inputTime ]

    '''
    output = []

    for i in inputTime:

        sampleIsAtPosition = i % sampleWindow

        if(sampleIsAtPosition <= (sampleWindow / 2)):

            output.append(1.0/(timePeriod/baseFreqTimePeriod))
        else:
            output.append(0.0)

    return output
    '''

t = arange(0.0, numberOfPulses * baseFreqTimePeriod, samplingFreqTimePeriod)

baseFreqFn = baseFreq(t, baseFreqTimePeriod)
plot(t, baseFreqFn, linewidth=1.0)

baseFreqFn = baseFreq(t, 2 * baseFreqTimePeriod)
plot(t, baseFreqFn, linewidth=2.0)

baseFreqFn = baseFreq(t, 3 * baseFreqTimePeriod)
plot(t, baseFreqFn, linewidth=2.0)

xlabel('time (uS)')
ylabel('Amplitude')
title('Test')
grid(True)
show()
```

This generates the output:

[image]

Instead, this would make me happy (only first few arrows drawn)

[image]

Also, notice how the display window of the graph makes the top of the full amplitude wave clip? (bottom bits are obscured as well)

It would be great if I could see the peak-to-peak values (the axis extend beyond the range of the data), like in here:

[image] (http://web.mit.edu/6.02/www/f2009/handouts/labs/lab2_7_1.png)

Comment: This is a good question, but it might be hard for others to appreciate it because it's not clearly stated as a question; it's just a list of wishes. Maybe next time try: "How do you make an arrow pointing up and an arrow pointing down?" and "How do you adjust the range/limits of the plot?". Having a question helps others find your question and the corresponding answers, because you're probably not the only one with the question. Also it helps to say what you know and don't know, so nothing is repeated, e.g. I can't find documentation on making an arrow, or there are no examples, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To make an arrow, you can use the `arrow` routine:

```
     #x,y, dx, dy,
arrow(0,0,  0,1.0,
    'lw':2,
    'color':'black',
    'head_width':baseFreqTimePeriod/4,
    'head_length':0.05
```

to make a downward pointing arrow, set a negative dy.:

```
arrow(baseFreqTimePeriod,0,  0,-1.0,
    'lw':2,
    'color':'black',
    'head_width':baseFreqTimePeriod/4,
    'head_length':0.05
```

To change the limits of the plot, use `xlim` and `ylim':

```
ylim([-.2,1.2])
xlim([-.1*t[-1],t[-1]*1.1])
```

There is documentation on [arrow](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.arrow), [xlim](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim) and [ylim](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ylim). It is also possible to make an arrow with text, using the [annotate](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) method.

Comment: I liked your comment on the way I posted the question! Tried out your suggestions :-)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Feel free to let me know if this is what you wanted and was the answer you were looking for. Good luck...